# Linker errors in Monterrey

Tags: xcode, python, development, macos

I'm trying to build a native python module on Monterrey and I'm getting the following error:

```
gcc -arch x86_64 -fno-strict-aliasing -O -fPIC -shared -lpython2.7  build/nodepos.o build/pyspidermonkey.o -L/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib -Lspidermonkey/src/build -ljs -o build/pyspidermonkey.so
ld: cannot link directly with dylib/framework, your binary is not an allowed client of /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/MacOSX.platform/Developer/SDKs/MacOSX.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/libpython2.7.tbd for architecture x86_64
```

I get that Apple has deprecated the bundled python, that's fine. I do have my own install of python2.7. How do I make sure that gets used and not Apple's? Or how do I make my build an allowed client?

Comment: Hi! Where you able to resolve this issue?

Comment: Nope. Still broken.